# Android: Bottom Sheet text view not updating

Tags: android, textview, bottom-sheet

Here is my code:

```
public void openBottomSheet(long id) {
    final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.coordinator_layout);

    _bottomSheet.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
    _bottomSheet.setPeekHeight(140);
    coordinatorLayout.requestLayout();

    Item item = _selected.getItem(id);

    final String titleText = item.getTitleText();
    _bottomSheetTitle.setText(titleText);
    coordinatorLayout.requestLayout();

    int imageResource = (id > 5) ? R.drawable.ic_closed : R.drawable.ic_open;
    _bottomSheetState.setBackgroundResource(imageResource);

    coordinatorLayout.requestLayout();
    coordinatorLayout.invalidate();
}
```

Firstly, I'm broadly having the issue described at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205226 where they suggested `requestLayout()` was the solution.

And it does sort of fix it. However, I am finding the *first* time I open the bottom sheet (by clicking some other element in the UI) the text does not load. The second, third, fourth and so on time, the text *does* update. So it's just on that initial load that it's not quite working.

The image resource seems to load fine on the first attempt. It's just the textview not updating.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

#### Edit

I've tried putting the `requestLayout()` in a number of places to see if it would make a difference.